# My application is not opening on clicking deep link url

Tags: android, deep-linking

Here is code the approach I am using.

`

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="www.omega.dk" />
            <data android:host="omega" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/wso2_scheme" />
            <data android:path="/app/examptpassword" />
           
        </intent-filter>`
```

Here is a line which is I am clicking.

https://www.omega.dk/app/examptpassword

I have tried multiple Solutions but all in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this schema too in your intent filter.
 `<data android:scheme="https"/>`

Comment: OMG How can I skip this? Thanks @Azeem Haider its working now.